# Trying to confirm my answer (Integral)

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easier method to this integration problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53974/is-there-an-easier-method-to-this-integration-problem)

I am trying to solve this problem: $\int \ln \sqrt{x^2-4}dx \quad$[W|A Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int:%20lnsqrt%28x%5E2-4%29)

I was able to break it up using log rules to this: $\frac{1}{2} \left( \int \ln{(x+2)} dx + \int \ln{(x-2)} dx \right) \quad$[W|A Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29%28%28integrate%3A+ln%28x%2B2%29dx%29%2B%28integrate%3Aln%28x-2%29dx%29%29)

In the second form I am able to just do 2 by-parts integration's. After doing all the work and plugging in the solutions to the by parts integration's back into the second form to get a final answer of: $\frac{1}{2} \left( (x+2)(\ln (x+2) - 1) + (x-2)(\ln (x-2) - 1) \right) \quad$[W|A Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281/2%29%5B%28%28x%2b2%29%28ln%28x%2b2%29%E2%88%921%29%29%2b%28%28x%E2%88%922%29%28ln%28x%E2%88%922%29%E2%88%921%29%29%5D)

Since W|A's answers are always throughly simplified and what not I am not 100% sure whether my final answer is correct, could anyone help me confirm it?

Comment: Haven't you asked this already here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53974 ?

Comment: "could anyone help me confirm it?" - differentiate your result and see if it gives back your original integrand.

Comment: No, This is sort of a follow up.

Comment: Please try to keep your posts self-contained. I have added tex to flush out your post. Please correct me if I was in error. I have not read your previous question, so I'm out of the loop there.

Comment: @mwmnj: Your previous post had also been edited by someone else to make it self-contained. Please try to learn from such edits so they won't be required in the future.

Comment: Note that the W|A answer is rather inconvenient, as it includes a constant of $\pm\pi \mathrm i$ in the region $|x|\ge2$ where the integrand is real.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Taking a derivative will undo the integration. Take it and see if it's correct.

Comment: We should make a T-shirt of out this :)